# Can't load batteries using FindLib in Ocaml TopLevel

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, ocaml-batteries

I successfully installed `ocaml-batteries-included` and `findlib`.

I can do 'ocamlfind ocamlc -package batteries -c mycode.ml` without problems.

Also, if I do `ocamlfind list`, I get

```
$ ocamlfind list
batteries           (version: 2.0)
batteries.pa_comprehension (version: 2.0)
batteries.pa_comprehension.syntax (version: 2.0)
batteries.pa_llist  (version: 2.0)
batteries.pa_llist.syntax (version: 2.0)
batteries.pa_string (version: 2.0)
batteries.pa_string.syntax (version: 2.0)
batteries.syntax    (version: 2.0)
bigarray            (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
camlp4              (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
...
```

---

The problem is `using batteries` in `ocaml (toplevel)`.

I have set up `.ocamlinit` as told:

```
#use "topfind";;

Toploop.use_silently
             Format.err_formatter (Filename.concat (Findlib.package_directory
             "batteries") "battop.ml");;
```

but when I launch `ocaml`, I get this:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.00.1

Findlib has been successfully loaded. Additional directives:
  #require "package";;      to load a package
  #list;;                   to list the available packages
  #camlp4o;;                to load camlp4 (standard syntax)
  #camlp4r;;                to load camlp4 (revised syntax)
  #predicates "p,q,...";;   to set these predicates
  Topfind.reset();;         to force that packages will be reloaded
  #thread;;                 to enable threads

Exception: Fl_package_base.No_such_package ("batteries", "").
```

Further, if I do `#list` in `ocaml toplevel`, I get

```
# #list;;
bigarray            (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
camlp4              (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
camlp4.exceptiontracer (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
camlp4.extend       (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
...
```

**I can't see `batteries` package.**

---

**What's the problem?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a reason why you're not using OPAM? (https://github.com/OCamlPro/opam)

Install OPAM, switch to your favorite version of the 4.0x compiler (for example `opam switch 4.00.1`), and run: `opam install batteries`. I recommend doing `opam install utop` and using `utop` instead of the vanilla toplevel. In either case:

Put the following in your `~/.ocamlinit`

```
#use "topfind";;
#require "batteries";;
open Batteries;;
```

This is all you need to get batteries working.

Comment: Hi I have done all these. As I indicated in the beginning, `I successfully installed ocaml-batteries-included and findlib.

I can do 'ocamlfind ocamlc -package batteries -c mycode.ml` without problems.` I can use batteries in file but not in toplevel. I get `# #require "batteries";;
No such package: batteries` error.

Comment: I have tried `opam switch 4.00.1` and `opam install batteries`, still I can't find `batteries` in `ocaml toplevel`.

Comment: have you done `eval \`opam config env\`` after `opam switch 4.00.1`? I tested my instructions on a clean install and they've worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Ok, I just tried `opam config -evn`. still not working for batteries.Exception: Fl_package_base.No_such_package ("batteries", "").